# How can you access iOS Contacts "found in apps"?

Tags: ios, contacts-framework

I have an app that uses the Contacts Framework to retrieve information about a user's contacts. If I launch the Apple Contacts app and do a search for some users, I get data about contacts "found in other apps" such as Mail. However, when I try to retrieve all contacts in code, I do not get these users returned.

I am retrieving contact information using the following code:

```
let store = CNContactStore()
store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (success, error) in
if success == true {
    let keysToFetch: [CNKeyDescriptor] = [
        CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
        CNContactEmailAddressesKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
        CNContactInstantMessageAddressesKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
        CNContactPostalAddressesKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
        CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey as CNKeyDescriptor]

    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
    fetchRequest.mutableObjects = true
    fetchRequest.unifyResults = true
    fetchRequest.sortOrder = .userDefault

    do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (contact, stop) -> Void in
        // Process results here...
    } catch {

    }
}
```

Below is a screenshot of user data in the Contacts app that does NOT show up in the data returned. Note that this data also does not show up in the Contacts app if I just scroll to where they should be. They are only there when I do a search.

Does anyone know how to get access to these contacts "found in other apps" using the Contacts Framework?

[image]

Comment: I doubt that apple offers an api to do so. it wouldn't make much sense, if an app must get permission to get contacts from the address book, but other apps would expose them.

Comment: I would think if it does exist, it would still be accessed through the Contacts Framework (so the user would still have a way to give you permission to view such information).

Comment: Did you ever come across an app that ask you to access contacts from some other app? I didnt.

Comment: In iOS 10 there are ways you can suggest data about users to the system using INInteraction.dontate. This lets you tell the system things such as "here is an email for a user". The contacts app uses this to populate that data. Some of that data is linked to existing users, but sometimes they show up in the "found in other apps" section. Since the system knows about it and can pull it in already, I am trying to find out how to access that data. I am not trying to talk with the individual apps directly, just though the Contacts Framework that (hopefully) already knows about that data.

Comment: @lehn0058 did you ever come across an answer for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet.